# PhP pdf validation not working with finfo_file

Tags: php, if-statement

Okay guys, go easy. I am a complete novice at PhP and bulldozing my way through it. I want to validate an uploaded file is indeed a PDF. Everything works except my if statement doesn't seem to pick up the application/pdf string if it is actually a pdf or not. I always comes back as invalid. I know its something stupid with my syntax or something. But it has been doing my head in trying to figure it out.

```
 $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); // return mime type ala mimetype  extension
 $check= finfo_file($finfo,$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]). "\n";

    finfo_close($finfo);}

if($check == 'application/pdf') {
    echo "File is a PDF - &nbsp";
    $uploadOk = 1;
} else {
    echo "File is not a valid PDF file - &nbsp";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
```

Comment: You append a `\n` to `$check`? Try `var_dump($check)` to see what the value is.

Comment: omg! thank you so much. I love you!